# Como evitar conflitos de bibliotecas jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boas, 
Vou tentar explicar pois **sou novato**. Bom preciso usar uma nova biblioteca, e

esse codigo funciona perfeitamente quando sozinho com onesse exemplo:

```
< script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">< /script >
<script>
  meu codigo
< /script >
```

Mas **se preciso** adicionar mais "jquersxxx.js"   todo o java da pagina para de funcionar, e no "console do inspector" posso ver todo tipo de erro como

```
form:699 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).minicolors is not a function
common-scripts.js?1455274914:87 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).niceScroll is not a function
sparkline-chart.js?1449132462:21 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sparkline is not a function
```

Então buscando no amigo google, achei a seguinte opção:

```
< script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" >
jQuery.noConflict(); 

meu código

< /script >
```

Mas o erro continua, todo o java da pagina simplesmente para de funcionar da mesma forma...  eu simplesmente nao sei como usar esse recurso

Por favor alguém pode me mostrar como evitar/ajustar isso? os exemplos da net sao sempre teoricos... eu ja to buscando isso a 3 dias...

obs: Exemplos de como usar são sempre muito bem vindos!

Comment: **Nota**: Não confundir *Java* com *JavaScript*, são coisas diferentes.

Comment: Você já verificou se não é o javascript que esta desativado? tente fazer algo simples em js puro como `alert('js funcionando');`.

Comment: fiz o teste,  o JavaScript funciona bacaninha!  e meu codigo local. em um **arqui.html** fica bom tambem.   Mas quando vou colocar no servidor...  onde tem mais codigo de outros participantes... todo o JavaScript para...  bom, se tiver mais dicas agradeco!

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 se o código não funciona online o problema pode ser que seus plugins não estão sendo carregados corretamente. O erro `$(...).niceScroll is not a function` indica que seu plugin não foi inserido no jQuery. Você está incluindo estes plugins antes ou depois do jQuery? Seu código vem antes ou depois dos scripts dos plugins? Remonte a parte do seu código no [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) e coloque o link na pergunta para podermos analisar melhor se o problema se encontra no seu código ou nos plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Se você olhar a [documentação do `.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) verá que ele serve apenas para evitar o conflito com outras libs que usam o símbolo `$`.

No seu caso, creio que o problema seja na tag script. Tags script com o atributo `src` devem ser vazias, portanto remova o código de dentro dela e coloque em outra tag, assim:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
   // seu código aqui 
</script>
```

Comment: Ola Guilherme, editei a pergunta, pois ach oque assim fica mais clara...  poderia comentar novamente, por favor?  sera que consegui me explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Coloque seu código JQuery dentro de um [`wrapper`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper) JQuery:

Podem ser os seguintes:

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Código JQuery aqui
});
```

Ou ainda:

```html
jQuery.noConflict();
 
(function( $ ) {
    //Codigo JQuery aqui
})( jQuery );
```

O meu preferido é:

```html
$(function(){
    //Codigo JQuery aqui
});
```

Lembre-se de que o símbolo `$` ([açúcar sintático](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1tico)) é um atalho para um objeto `JQuery()`.

Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JQuery Teste</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var resultado = $('#select option:selected').text();
                alert(resultado);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="select">
            <option selected>Olá, mundo!!!</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não, não. Vou editar e colocar um exemplo.

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora